# slice of channels and concurrent function execution

Tags: go, goroutine

How to create slice of channels and run function `double(i)` concurrently inside slice iteration:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func double(i int) int {
    result := 2 * i
    fmt.Println(result)
    time.Sleep(500000000)
    return result
}

func notParallel(arr []int) (outArr []int) {
    for _, i := range arr {
        outArr = append(outArr, double(i))
    }
    return
}

// how to do the same as notParallel func in parallel way.
// For each element of array double func should evaluate concuruntly
// without waiting each next element to eval
func parallel(arr []int) (outArr []int) {

    var chans []chan int
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        chans[i] = make(chan int) // i = 0 : panic: runtime error: index out of range
    }

    for counter, number := range arr {
        go func() {
            chans[counter] <- double(number)
        }()
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", notParallel(arr))
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", parallel(arr))
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FwaBKXAF2q)

As function `double(i)` sleeps for 500 ms function `notParallel(arr []int)` works for 1500 ms for 3 elements of `arr []int` but function `parallel(arr []int)` would work about 500 ms.

In my implementation have error...

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

... on line ...

```
chans[i] = make(chan int) // i = 0
```

Comment: The answer below is great, but answering your particular question, `var chans []chan int` is only declaring `chans`, but you need to allocate it too. It can be done in a single statement with `chans := make([]chan int, len(arr))`. This is not particular for `chan`, but general for slices of any type.

Comment: Side nit: don't do `time.Sleep(500000000)`, instead do `time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)`.

Comment: Another nit: [slices and arrays are very different in Go](https://blog.golang.org/slices), you repeated refer to a slice as an array which at minimum is an error in the comments but could also be a sign of a serious misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to use chan.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func double(i int) int {
    result := 2 * i
    fmt.Println(result)
    time.Sleep(500000000)
    return result
}

func notParallel(arr []int) (outArr []int) {
    for _, i := range arr {
        outArr = append(outArr, double(i))
    }
    return
}

// how to do the same as notParallel func in parallel way.
// For each element of array double func should evaluate concuruntly
// without waiting each next element to eval
func parallel(arr []int) (outArr []int) {
    outArr = make([]int, len(arr))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for counter, number := range arr {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(counter int, number int) {
            outArr[counter] = double(number)
            wg.Done()
        }(counter, number)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", notParallel(arr))
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", parallel(arr))
}
```

Because parallel must wait all of finish of goroutine(s).

And I notice your code doesn't work because you refer `counter`, `number` in same function scope.

Comment: Minor comment for those that may not be aware of it: when you know ahead of time how many times `wg.Add(1)` will be called it can be beneficial to just do `wg.Add(len(arr))` once before the loop. All wait group calls require synchronization so it can be helpful to minimize such calls. Of course, if you think it's clearer or more readable (or if you don't know the total ahead of time) then calling `wg.Add(1)` is perfectly fine too.